# format the following result file into a tabular format using Perl

Tags: string, perl, csv, string-formatting

I have a sort of a problem, and I am still novice with Perl.

I just want to ask how can I format the following results file into an Excel readable format (let's say CSV).

Result file example. `llq1_dly.mt0`

```
$MEAS COMMANDS SOURCE='llq1_dly.meas' DB FILE='clk_top_45h_lpe_sim.fsdb'
.TITLE '**-------------'
    tdrll10_0        tdfll10_0        tdrll10_1        tdfll10_1        tdrll10_2        tdfll10_2        tdrll10_3
 2.106560e-10     1.990381e-10     2.102583e-10     1.986280e-10     2.095036e-10     1.978480e-10     2.083813e-10
```

into the following file with a result like this one below

```
llq1_dly,tdr,tdf,
ll10_0,2.106560e-10,1.990381e-10,
ll10_1,2.102583e-10,1.986280e-10,
ll10_2,2.095036e-10,1.978480e-10,
ll10_3,2.083813e-10,1.967019e-10,
...
```

or more likely this one (to be compatible with engineering scientific notations):

```
llq1_dly,tdr,tdf,
ll10_0,210.6560e-12,199.0381e-12,
ll10_1,210.2583e-12,198.6280e-12,
ll10_2,209.5036e-12,197.8480e-12,
ll10_3,208.3813e-12,196.7019e-12,
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a program that produces the output you ask for. I don't generally approve of offering answers to questions where the OP hasn't made any attempt to write a solution themselves, but this question interested me.

It may well be that this could be written more simply, but you don't say what parts of the input are invariant. For instance, I have written it so that there can be any number of different columns with any names, rather than just `tdr` and `tdf` every time. As it is I have had to guess that the trailing part of each header ends in `ll`, so for instance `tdrll10_0` is `tdr` and `ll10_0`. If that is wrong then you will need a different way of splitting the string.

I have written the program so that it reads from the `DATA` file handle. I trust you are able to write an `open` statement to read from the correct input file?

I hope this helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Number::FormatEng 'format_eng';
Number::FormatEng::use_e_zero();

my $fh = \*DATA;

my ($source, @headers, @values);
while ( <$fh> ) {
  if ( /SOURCE=(?|'([^']+)'|"([^"]+)")/ ) { #' code highlighting fix
    ($source = $1) =~ s/\.[^.]*\z//;
  }
  elsif ( /^\.TITLE/ ) {
    @headers = split ' ', <$fh>;
    @values  = split ' ', <$fh>;
    last;
  }
}

my @title = ( $source );
my (%headers, @table, @line);
for my $i ( 0 .. $#headers) {
  my @fields = split /(?=ll)/, $headers[$i];
  if ( $headers{$fields[0]} ) {
    push @table, [ @line ];
    @line = ();
    %headers = ();
  }
  ++$headers{$fields[0]};
  push @line, $fields[1] if @line == 0;
  push @line, format_eng($values[$i]);
  push @title, $fields[0] unless @table;
}
print "$_," for @title;
print "\n";

for ( @table ) {
  print "$_," for @$_;
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
$MEAS COMMANDS SOURCE='llq1_dly.meas' DB FILE='clk_top_45h_lpe_sim.fsdb'
.TITLE '**-------------'
    tdrll10_0        tdfll10_0        tdrll10_1        tdfll10_1        tdrll10_2        tdfll10_2        tdrll10_3
 2.106560e-10     1.990381e-10     2.102583e-10     1.986280e-10     2.095036e-10     1.978480e-10     2.083813e-10
```

**output**

```
llq1_dly,tdr,tdf,
ll10_0,210.656e-12,199.0381e-12,
ll10_1,210.2583e-12,198.628e-12,
ll10_2,209.5036e-12,197.848e-12,
```

Comment: @Borodin 

Can you explain to me what the code highlighted fix section do? I am not yet familiar with regex'es. Thanks

Comment: @Meeyaw: That checks whether the current line contains `SOURCE=` followed by a single- or double-quoted string, and captures (in `$1`) the string inside the quotes. The comment is just a single quote to prevent the code highlighter from getting confused: without it it thinks the whole of the rest of the program is a string literal